# OpenApi CodeGen validating fields despite setting performBeanValidation to false

Tags: java, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

My current setup:

```
configurations {
    openApiGenerator
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:4.0.1'
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
    openApiGenerator 'org.openapitools:openapi-generator-cli:6.6.0'
}

def openApiGeneratorConfig = {
    classpath configurations.openApiGenerator
    mainClass = 'org.openapitools.codegen.OpenAPIGenerator'
    args 'generate'
    args '-g', 'java'
    args '-o', "$projectDir"
    args '-t', "$projectDir/src/main/resources/openapi-config/templates"
    args "--additional-properties", "library=feign," +
            "dateLibrary=java8," +
            "useBeanValidation=false," +
            "performBeanValidation=false"
}

task generateApi(type: JavaExec) {
    configure openApiGeneratorConfig
    systemProperties = ['apis': '', 'models': '']
    args '-i', 'https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.yaml'
    args '-c', "$projectDir/src/main/resources/openapi-config/pet.json"
}
```

I'm setting both useBeanValidation and performBeanValidation to false yet I still get @javax.annotation.Nullable annotations in my model fields.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using the cli in gradle instead of using the gradle plugin?

Comment: @tbatch I remember having a hard setting up configuration with gradle plugin so I went with cli